# How do I convert . input to 0. in QLineEdit in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to make a window-based program where I have to input values into several different QLineEdit boxes, and where any text change will trigger a calculation function (e.g. the sum of different boxes).

I have already been successful at restricting number input using `QDoubleValidator`, but I know if I input anything other than a number, the program will crash. Hence my question about the decimal point separator, because I know future users will attempt at creating `0.*` values using only `.*`

As an example, I've done the following:

```
float_validator = QtGui.QDoubleValidator(self)
self.lineEdit_AC_CLmax.setValidator(float_validator)
CLmax  = float(self.lineEdit_AC_CLmax.text())
```

I have successfuly tested the program using numbers, but whenever I input `.`, the program crashes (there is no way of making `float('.')` to work, obviously).

Is there a way of restricting the use of `.` at first, allowing it only after the #1 digit in QLineEdit?
Alternatively, is there a way of converting `.` input into `0.`?

Comment: It would be extremely helpful to anyone attempting to help you if you were to include your sample program or at least a trimmed down generic version of it. With that we would be able to just simply copy and run it and then help you fix the issues you are having. This kind of question as posted leaves far to many unknowns requiring folks to make far to many assumptions that could end up making you more confused.

Comment: Secondary note you ought not trigger the recalculation until the user has finished their input as this could cause unexpected results and unnecessary issues such as the program crashing (as in your case -or- what if the calculation used the value to divide by and the user was attempting to put in 0.5 when they typed 0 the program would crash). I would restrict the validation and recalculation to after the users has pressed enter or clicked elsewhere indicating they have completed their entry.

Comment: Sorry, I agree with you, next time I will post a bigger section, it's just that I am not allowed to share much of this program, plus I am new to the website xD
I also agree with your second note, I'll remake the triggering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For solutions I am there are several approaches:

### - It could be restricted so that the first digit is not ".":

```py
class DoubleValidator(QtGui.QDoubleValidator):
    def validate(self, _input, pos):
        res = super(DoubleValidator, self).validate(_input, pos)
        if _input == "." and pos == 1:
            res = (QtGui.QValidator.Invalid, _input, pos)
        return res 

# ...
validator_a = DoubleValidator(self, notation=QtGui.QDoubleValidator.StandardNotation)
self.le_a = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
self.le_a.setValidator(validator_a)
# ...
```

But the same should be done with "+" and "-" since they generate the same problem, but do not you think it would be inappropriate? For example: How do you place a negative value? You would have to place at least one digit and then move the cursor to the beginning to place the sign, that would be too uncomfortable. So for me it is not a reasonable solution.

### - Validate the text before performing the operation:

The user should not have more restrictions than necessary, in this case I think that it would be enough to validate the cases in which even the float is not valid and establish in the calculation a default value, for example a "0":

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        validator_a = QtGui.QDoubleValidator(self, notation=QtGui.QDoubleValidator.StandardNotation)
        self.le_a = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(textChanged=self.update_result)
        self.le_a.setValidator(validator_a)

        validator_b = QtGui.QDoubleValidator(self, notation=QtGui.QDoubleValidator.StandardNotation)
        self.le_b = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(textChanged=self.update_result)
        self.le_b.setValidator(validator_b)

        self.result_label = QtWidgets.QLabel()

        lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.le_a)
        lay.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel("+"))
        lay.addWidget(self.le_b)
        lay.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel("="))
        lay.addWidget(self.result_label)

        self.update_result()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def update_result(self):
        a = self.le_a.text()
        b = self.le_b.text()
        if a in ("", ".", "-", "+"):
            a = 0
        if b in ("", ".", "-", "+"):
            b = 0
        res = float(a) + float(b)
        self.result_label.setNum(res)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = Widget()
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

### - Do not use QLineEdit but QDoubleSpinBox :

Although QLineEdit allows to restrict characters to validate only numbers, it is best to use QDoubleSpinBox that is specialized to obtain numerical values from the user:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.sp_a = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(valueChanged=self.update_result)
        self.sp_b = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(valueChanged=self.update_result)
        self.result_label = QtWidgets.QLabel()

        lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.sp_a)
        lay.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel("+"))
        lay.addWidget(self.sp_b)
        lay.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel("="))
        lay.addWidget(self.result_label)

        self.update_result()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def update_result(self):
        a = self.sp_a.value()
        b = self.sp_b.value()
        res = a + b
        self.result_label.setNum(res)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = Widget()
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I know I should have posted a bigger section of code not to overload you or anyone else, and for your work I thank you very much. I actually used @DennisJensen 's approach to change the trigger of the calculations, from an instant trigger of `textChanged` to an `editingfinished` signal. Then I used a mix of your first two solutions, only restricting the '-' sign (`editingfinished` actually solved the problem of the '.') and '0' for divisions. I also think the future user should know what he is doing and be smart at least xD

Comment: @PedroNunes never make the assumption that your user should know what they are doing because in my experience someone is going to break things and then its your fault for not having coded it in such a way to stop people from doing things that just do not make any sense to do or they should not have done -- such as put alphabetic characters into an obviously numeric oriented field.  Thus the implementation of fields that are numeric only -- accepting only numeric information.

Comment: @PedroNunes  As DennisJensen says the user is a free being and does not like to stick to the rules, your duty as a developer is that even if the user breaks the rules your SW survive, once in an SW engineering course they told me: "Anybody implements a function but our duty is that this function never fails even if others try it "(to fail in this context is not to break the program). Qt for this provides specialized widgets: IMHO the best solution is to use QDoubleSpinBox: it prevents the user from placing other unnecessary text besides just looking at it we know what works.